# Matching a font style exactly with QML

Tags: qt, fonts, qml, qtquick2

I have a QML app that's using a font family that has 5 weights—Light/Regular/Medium/Bold/Black—and 3 styles: Normal, Italic, and Condensed.

[image: font listing]

When I load both a 'normal' and 'condensed' style of the same weight they share the same family name; whichever style was loaded first is what is used:

```qml
FontLoader { source:"qrc:/fonts/DINPro-CondRegular.otf"; id:cond }
FontLoader { source:"qrc:/fonts/DINPro-Regular.otf";     id:norm }
Timer { running:true; onTriggered:console.log(id:norm.name==cond.name) } // outputs `true`

// This ends up using the condensed flavor
Text { text:'hi mom'; font { family:'DINPro' } }
```

Is there some way to tell a `Text` object to use a specific font file or `FontLoader` instance? There's an [`italic` property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#fontInfo.italic-prop) for italic style, but no property for the 'condensed' flavor.

How can I use both normal and condensed styles of the font in the same document, and specify which to use for different `Text`?

Answer (score 3):

I've found that for this particular font I can use the [`styleName` property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#fontInfo.styleName-prop) to control the various flavors. I just kept trying various style strings until I found ones that worked.

```
FontLoader { source:"qrc:/fonts/DINPro-Regular.otf"     }
FontLoader { source:"qrc:/fonts/DINPro-CondRegular.otf" }
FontLoader { source:"qrc:/fonts/DINPro-CondMedium.otf"  }

Text { text:'norm'; font { family:'DINPro';                    styleName:'Regular' } }
Text { text:'bold'; font { family:'DINPro'; weight:Font.Bold;  styleName:'Regular' } }
Text { text:'blak'; font { family:'DINPro'; weight:Font.Black; styleName:'Regular' } }
Text { text:'cond norm'; font { family:'DINPro'; styleName:'CondRegular' } }    
Text { text:'cond bold'; font { family:'DINPro'; styleName:'CondBold'    } }    
Text { text:'cond blak'; font { family:'DINPro'; styleName:'CondBlack'   } }
```

It feels like it's held together with tape and string, but it's working. If someone has a more robust way to handle this—especially to know exactly what strings will work for the `styleName`—I'll happily accept that answer instead of this one.

Comment: I've come to a similar conclusion. Turns out the `name` property of all the `FontLoader` components are the same. So you need to specify styles by properties such as `weight` and `styleName`, which as you say, seems far from precise. It's a trial-and-error process for me too. Really surprised this is not documented more clearly. QML and CSS seem to have both taken the "suggest rather than command" approach to programming.