# How do I get two FontLoaders in QML to work?

Tags: qt, fonts, qml

Using QML, I have defined two FontLoaders in a pragma Singleton file. I can only get one of these fonts to display when I run my program inside QML scene. How can I get both of the fonts I've defined to render? Thank you!

```
// Defining two fonts inside Fonts.qml:

pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.4

QtObject {

    readonly property var primaryFont: FontLoader {
        source: "../assets/fonts/CircularStd-Book.ttf"
    }

    readonly property var boldFont: FontLoader {
        source: "../assets/fonts/CircularStd-Bold.otf"
    }

}

// Calling both fonts in separate QML file:

import QtQuick 2.4
import "../../../imports/Fonts.qml"

Text {
    id: welcomeMessage
    text: "Good Morning"
    font.family: Fonts.primaryFont.name
}

Text {
    id: driverName
    text: "Joe"
    font.family: Fonts.boldFont.name
}
```

I'm expecting the welcomeMessage text to display with a normal font weight and the driverName text to display with a bold font weight. However, both fonts display with a normal font weight.

If I comment out primaryFont in my pragma Singleton, then driverName displays in bold. Why can I not get both of these fonts to load?

Comment: What are the two values of"name"? As both seem to be from the same base font, they might have the same name and get merged, then you would to have to use bold: true or the weight property, I think.

Comment: You should set driverName font.bold: true to make it work.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld you are right! I ran a console.log on the font.family name and both the bold and primary font are receiving a value of "Circular Std." I tried to manually override this with a custom name in my FontLoader, but then the font did not load at all. I assume the font name is coming from its metadata or something?

Comment: We also came to the conclusion that the `name` property is unpredictable here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45242560/matching-a-font-style-exactly-with-qml#comment124941800_45243341

Answer (score 0):

```
Text {
    id: driverName
    text: "Joe"
    font.family: Fonts.boldFont.name
    font.bold: true
}
```

Add this to make it work:
font.bold: true

Comment: This absolutely does work, thank you for the suggestion! However, it's important for my project that I have the capability to actually load multiple fonts. As @FrankOsterfeld pointed out, QML seems to think both the bold and normal weight font families are the same–i.e., they show a value of "Circular Std" when I run a console.log.

Comment: @JoelMertz There is no other way to do it. You will never make font bold without setting this property. You did load multiple fonts.

Comment: OK, interesting! I was expecting the bold font to load and display as bold. I also have this problem when trying to display semibold, light, and other unique, custom designed font weights in the same font-family. For now, I will load the bold font and tell it to be bold! Thank you.

Comment: @JoelMertz There is font.weight property for more specific setting.
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-font.html